# How to adapt automatically and easily a plane texture to a 3d object

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, texture-painting

I'm trying to do *projection painting* because I want to apply a texture found on te net to my bird, instead of coloring it by/with my hands. The  tutorial that I'm following can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J32ptRl-b9A).

I'm using this tutorial because the model used there is very similar to mine. The problem I have is that I'm not able to adapt the texture to the *UV maps* of my model. On the tutorial he used *proportional editing* and has been able to do a good job. I tried to do the same with my model, but I'm having problems probably because I haven't understood how to use *proportional editing* well. Is there another way to do this? Or do you have some suggestion to give me to improve my skill using *proportional editing*? Thanks.

I attach a screenshot to show you where I'm having problems:

[image: pic]

PS : Maybe the image found is not good for my UVs,but I don't know how to find a better one.

PS 2 : [image]

Comment: Proportional editing is a way of editing the neighboring geometry/objects to your selection within a configurable radius or area of influence and a configurable falloff function. You can control the radius with your mouse wheel. It is however limited in scope, it is good for small to medium sized changes, but wont allow a full fledged morphing from one mesh o the other. You may need to start from a mesh that is more similar in shape to your bird's silhouette

Comment: Hello. Can you explain how can I find a picture of a bird that can match perfectly my bird's silhouette ? Is there a method to do it ?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to do, but it's not so much the picture that must match your bird (although it also helps) but the mesh you are trying to deform. You can search the internet for 3D models of birds, although that wont be easy it's probably better if you model it yourself.

Comment: I'm trying to find a good picture of a bird that makes easier to model the mesh,like this : http://postimg.org/image/ewngxhokr/

Comment: Part of the problem may be that the mesh you are using seems to be for a carttonish bird with unrealistic proportions, making it match a real bird may be difficult. Maybe one of these may help https://www.google.com/search?q=parrot+3d+model